# Batch code to read a file and check if all records of the specified size and no duplicates occur too

Tags: batch-file

I have this piece of code that sorts my input file abc.txt and tells me if there are any duplicates, I need to modify this piece to also tell me if there are any records that exceed the size specified by reclen.

```
@echo off
rem setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set inputfile=abc.txt
set outputfile=text2.txt
set reclen=100
echo File to be processed
echo.
type %inputfile%
echo.
if exist sorted.txt del sorted.txt
sort %inputfile% /O sorted.txt

if exist %outputfile% del %outputfile%
echo Duplicates are as follows>>%outputfile%
set lastline=
for /f "delims==" %%L in (sorted.txt) do (
set thisline=%%L
if "!thisline!"=="!lastline!" echo !thisline!>>%outputfile%
    set lastline=%%L
)

pause
```

del sorted.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if a string exceeds a length limit, simply test if a substring of length limit does not match the original string.

```
if "!thisline:~0,%reclen%!" neq "!thisline!" echo Line length exceeded
```

Here is a complete working solution

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

set "inputfile=abc.txt"
set "outputfile=text2.txt"
set reclen=100
echo File to be processed
echo(
type "%inputfile%"
echo(
if exist sorted.txt del sorted.txt
sort %inputfile% /O sorted.txt
set "lastline="
> "%outputfile%" (
  for /f "delims==" %%L in (sorted.txt) do (
    set "thisline=%%L"
    if "!thisline!" equ "!lastline!" echo(DUPLICATE: !thisline!
    if "!thisline:~0,%reclen%!" neq "!thisline!" echo( TOO LONG: !thisline!
    set "lastline=%%L"
  )
)
del sorted.txt
type "%outputfile%"
pause
```

Note that the above can fail if your data contains `!`. That can be solved by toggling delayed expansion on and off within the loop.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion

set "inputfile=abc.txt"
set "outputfile=text2.txt"
set reclen=100
echo File to be processed
echo(
type "%inputfile%"
echo(
if exist sorted.txt del sorted.txt
sort %inputfile% /O sorted.txt
set "lastline="
> "%outputfile%" (
  for /f "delims==" %%L in (sorted.txt) do (
    set "thisline=%%L"
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    if "!thisline!" equ "!lastline!" echo(DUPLICATE: !thisline!
    if "!thisline:~0,%reclen%!" neq "!thisline!" echo( TOO LONG: !thisline!
    endlocal
    set "lastline=%%L"
  )
)
del sorted.txt
type "%outputfile%"
pause
```

Finally, as requested by the OP in comments, here is a version that identifies lines that do not match the length specified by reclen. It only requires 2 small changes from the previous version.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion

set "inputfile=abc.txt"
set "outputfile=text2.txt"
set reclen=100
echo File to be processed
echo(
type "%inputfile%"
echo(
if exist sorted.txt del sorted.txt
sort %inputfile% /O sorted.txt
set "lastline="
> "%outputfile%" (
  for /f "delims==" %%L in (sorted.txt) do (
    set "thisline=%%L"
    set "testline=%%Lx"
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    if "!thisline!" equ "!lastline!" echo( DUPLICATE: !thisline!
    if "!testline:~0,%reclen%!" neq "!thisline!" echo(BAD LENGTH: !thisline!
    endlocal
    set "lastline=%%L"
  )
)
del sorted.txt
type "%outputfile%"
pause
```

If the line is longer than reclen, then the substring will truncate the value and it will NOT match the original.

If the line has length exactly equal to reclen, then the subtring will only trim the `x`, and it WILL match the original.

If the line is shorter than reclen, then the substring will not remove the `x`, and it will NOT match the original.

Comment: Doesnt seem to be working it echo's out all the lines saying Line Length exceeded.

Comment: @VineetKalra - Not sure what you have wrong. It works fine for me.

Comment: Ok this is what I corrected it to, let me know if I am wrong somewhere.
...
if exist %outputfile% del %outputfile%
echo Duplicates are as follows>>%outputfile%
set lastline=
for /f "delims==" %%L in (sorted.txt) do (
 set thisline=%%L
 if "!thisline!"=="!lastline!" echo !thisline!>>%outputfile%

        set lastline=%%L
        if "!thisline:~0,%reclen%!" neq "!thisline!" echo !thisline! Line length exceeded

 )

del sorted.txt

pause

Comment: @VineetKalra - Not sure where you went wrong, but I've added a complete working solution to my answer.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your help the complete solution works, one small thing, I also need to make it work for records less than reclen basically not equal to reclen, why isnt the neq working to give me all the records that are not equal to the recelen, any help on that would be really great.

Comment: @VineetKalra - Ummm, If you wanted to test if the line length is equal to reclen, then you should have asked for that in the first place. Specifying a substring length that is greater than the length of the string does not extend the string, so of course the above does not detect lines that are too short. Why don't you take some more time to think about ways to detect if the line is too short. It can be done simply enough using techniques similar to the too long test. (similar - but not the same)

Comment: hmm, sorry about the question , should have framed it correctly, ya my requirement is to find records that are not equal to reclen size.And yes I think I know now the above code wouldnt work for less than,, m still thinking how I can do that...

Comment: @VineetKalra - I've added another version that meets your needs.

Comment: wow thanks, can you help me understand how the Lx part works does it look for the last available character on the line?

Comment: @VineetKalra - added explanation to answer

Comment: got it great, thanks.I think I need to refresh my logical thinking.. :)

Comment: I needed to add a few conditions to the code you gave me based on the response, the 2 conditions are 1) The output should only be written if the 5 th character is not equal to 8 and 2) 1st 8 characters of the line are alphanumerics.The utility seem to be failing due to the packed decimal fields in the first 8 bytes of the line.

Comment: I tried this but it doesnt seem to be working, whats incorrect in this statement, please guide.
    if "!thisline:~0,14!" equ "!lastline:~0,14!" if "!thisline:~4,1!" neq "8" if "!thisline:~0,1!" neq " " echo(DUPLICATE: !thisline!